# SUM of total per month with condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date, window-functions

I have a table, let's call them table SUMMARYDATA

```
NIP  NAME   DEPARTMENT       STATUSIN           STATUSOUT             TOTALLOSTTIME
------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
A1   ARIA   BB         2020-01-21 08:06:23  2020-01-21 11:58:36         01:05:00             
A1   ARIA   BB         2020-01-22 07:34:27  2020-01-22 17:19:47         00:30:00               
A1   ARIA   BB         2020-01-23 08:30:00  2020-01-23 11:00:00         00:00:00
A1   ARIA   BB         2020-01-24 08:05:00  2020-01-24 10:30:00         01:00:00
A2   BELLE  BB         2020-01-21 07:06:20  2020-01-21 13:58:31         00:30:00             
A2   BELLE  BB         2020-01-22 07:34:27  2020-01-22 17:19:47         00:15:00               
A2   BELLE  BB         2020-01-23 07:06:00  2020-01-23 10:30:00         00:00:00
A2   BELLE  BB         2020-01-24 09:06:00  2020-01-23 10:30:00         00:05:00
A3   CHLOE  CC         2020-01-21 07:06:23  2020-01-21 11:55:30         00:30:00             
A3   CHLOE  CC         2020-01-22 07:34:27  2020-01-22 17:00:44         01:00:00               
A3   CHLOE  CC         2020-01-23 08:37:00  2020-01-23 11:13:00         00:35:00
A3   CHLOE  CC         2020-01-24 08:09:00  2020-01-24 10:22:00         00:00:00
A4   ZIYA   CC         2020-01-21 07:06:20  2020-01-21 13:58:31         00:30:00             
A4   ZIYA   CC         2020-01-22 07:34:27  2020-01-22 17:19:47         00:15:00               
A4   ZIYA   CC         2020-01-23 06:06:00  2020-01-23 11:30:00         00:45:00
A4   ZIYA   CC         2020-01-24 09:06:00  2020-01-23 15:30:00         00:00:00
A5   BRIAN  BB         2020-01-21 08:06:23  2020-01-21 11:58:36         01:10:00             
A5   BRIAN  BB         2020-01-22 07:34:27  2020-01-22 17:19:47         01:00:00               
A5   BRIAN  BB         2020-01-23 08:30:00  2020-01-23 11:00:00         00:30:00
A5   BRIAN  BB         2020-01-24 08:05:00  2020-01-24 10:30:00         00:10:00
```

I need to `SELECT NIP,NAME,DEPARTMENT,STATUSIN,TOTALLOSTTIME` per month & per year `where sum(TOTALLOSTTIME) > '02:00:00'`. Then the datatype column in `TOTALLOSTTIME` is `nvarchar`

And this is the output that I meant:

```
    NIP  NAME   DEPARTMENT       STATUSIN           STATUSOUT             TOTALLOSTTIME
    ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
    A1   ARIA   BB         2020-01-21 08:06:23  2020-01-21 11:58:36         01:05:00             
    A1   ARIA   BB         2020-01-22 07:34:27  2020-01-22 17:19:47         00:30:00
    A1   ARIA   BB         2020-01-24 08:05:00  2020-01-24 10:30:00         01:00:00
    A3   CHLOE  CC         2020-01-21 07:06:23  2020-01-21 11:55:30         00:30:00             
    A3   CHLOE  CC         2020-01-22 07:34:27  2020-01-22 17:00:44         01:00:00               
    A3   CHLOE  CC         2020-01-23 08:37:00  2020-01-23 11:13:00         00:35:00 
    A5   BRIAN  BB         2020-01-21 08:06:23  2020-01-21 11:58:36         01:10:00             
    A5   BRIAN  BB         2020-01-22 07:34:27  2020-01-22 17:19:47         01:00:00               
    A5   BRIAN  BB         2020-01-23 08:30:00  2020-01-23 11:00:00         00:30:00
    A5   BRIAN  BB         2020-01-24 08:05:00  2020-01-24 10:30:00         00:10:00
```

And I've been try this query so far:

```
select NIP,NAME,DEPARTMENT,x.sum_lost_time,x.months,x.years
 from (select MONTH(STATUSIN)  as [months]
               ,YEAR(STATUSIN) as [years]
               ,NIP
               ,NAME
               ,DEPARTMENT         
               ,convert(varchar,dateadd(second,sum(datediff(second,'00:00:00',cast(TOTALLT as time))),0),108) as sum_lost_time
          from SUMMARYDATA b 
      group by MONTH(STATUSIN)
               ,YEAR(STATUSIN)
               ,NIP
               ,NAME
               ,DEPARTMENT
        )x
WHERE x.sum_lost_time > '10:00:00'
```

Comment: This is a broken schema. If you need to be able to do meaningful math with any value, you need a column type that supports that arithmetic. nvarchar is not it. Fix the schema, and suddenly the whole question becomes trivial.

Comment: maybe the datatype nvarchar is the only way i can do because the data is an unit of time @JoelCoehoorn

Comment: "unit of time" will happily fit into types other than varchar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want rows that belongs to a group whose total lost time is greater than 2 hours.

You can use window functions for this:

```
select nip, name, department, statusin, statusin, totallosttime
from (
    select 
        t.*,
        sum(
            left(totallosttime, 2) * 60 * 60 
            + substring(totallosttime, 4, 2) * 60 
            + right(totallosttime, 2)
        ) over(partition by 
            nip, 
            name, 
            department, 
            year(statusin), 
            month(statusin)
        ) totallostseconds
    from mytable t
) t
where totallostseconds >= 2 * 60 * 60
```

In the subquery, the window `sum()` computes the total "lost" duration for rows having the same `nip`, `name`, `department`, year and month. We use string functions to split `totallosttime` and turn it to a number of seconds. All that is left to do is to filter in the outer query.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=df790ba789f95381bf29795e455a6fa7)**:

```
nip | name  | department | statusin   | statusin   | totallosttime
:-- | :---- | :--------- | :--------- | :--------- | :------------
A1  | ARIA  | BB         | 2020-01-21 | 2020-01-21 | 01:05:00     
A1  | ARIA  | BB         | 2020-01-22 | 2020-01-22 | 00:30:00     
A1  | ARIA  | BB         | 2020-01-23 | 2020-01-23 | 00:00:00     
A1  | ARIA  | BB         | 2020-01-24 | 2020-01-24 | 01:00:00     
A3  | CHLOE | CC         | 2020-01-21 | 2020-01-21 | 00:30:00     
A3  | CHLOE | CC         | 2020-01-22 | 2020-01-22 | 01:00:00     
A3  | CHLOE | CC         | 2020-01-23 | 2020-01-23 | 00:35:00     
A3  | CHLOE | CC         | 2020-01-24 | 2020-01-24 | 00:00:00     
A5  | BRIAN | BB         | 2020-01-21 | 2020-01-21 | 01:10:00     
A5  | BRIAN | BB         | 2020-01-22 | 2020-01-22 | 01:00:00     
A5  | BRIAN | BB         | 2020-01-23 | 2020-01-23 | 00:30:00     
A5  | BRIAN | BB         | 2020-01-24 | 2020-01-24 | 00:10:00
```